# Mechanisms to move a view partly offscreen

Tags: ios7

I have a problem that nobody has yet offered any help with so let me ask a technical question to help me diagnose it on my own.

What mechanisms does the system have for moving a view so it appears to be partly off screen besides changing the view's frame (i.e. bounds/center) or transform?

This is an app which needs to run on iOS 5/6 still so I'm not using auto layout.
I have a fullscreen view reached via a push segue.
After a pause I hide the (translucent) status and navigation bars.
When the bars hide with animation they slide up off the screen.
In iOS 5/6 this just exposes the top of the view (which is an image).  In iOS 7 it moves the entire view up "offscreen" a corresponding amount (i.e. 64 points if I hide both bars) showing a bar of content "below" the view at the bottom of the screen.
When I un-hide the bars (via a tap) the bars appear and the view moves back down to occupy the whole screen.
Whether the VC is set to extend the view under bars or not doesn't affect the behavior.
I have not been able to reproduce this behavior in a simplified app.

In either state, i.e. partly offscreen or fully onscreen, the top-level view frame remains {0, 0} 320 x 480 and the transform matrix remains {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}.  I have no idea what property of what object the system is changing to visually move the view.  Perhaps if I knew what object/properties to examine I could deduce something about what is going on.  Can anybody tell me how the system might be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the "view" that was being moved was being presented by a UIPageViewController and I wasn't thinking about that.  The UIPageViewController is presenting the child views inside a UIScrollView (subclass, I think) and so the scroll insets for the containing UIScrollView were being changed by iOS 7.  Since the whole "presenting as a child" thing actually works -- of *course* I couldn't see the problem in the child view.

The "fix" was to un-check the View Controller setting for **Adjust Scroll View Insets** for the  UIPageViewController view.